# Modifying a string multiple times based on dict

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Minimal example:

**Code**

```
s = "A or B and C"
d = {"A": "1", "B": "0", "C": "0"}

for key, value in d.items():
    s = s.replace(key, value)

print(s)
```

**Output**

```
1 or 0 and 0
```

This code produces the desired output, i do however feel like there is a clever one-liner that can replace my loop.

Comment: You can use `str.translate`, but I would honestly suggest just keeping this code.

Comment: `s.translate(s.maketrans(d))` does indeed to the trick, but i think that the loop looks cleaner as well. Thank you!

Comment: Don't put an answer into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I'd recommend just keeping your code as it is:

```
s = "A or B and C"
d = {"A": "1", "B": "0", "C": "0"}

print(s.translate(s.maketrans(d)))
```

Output:

```
1 or 0 and 0
```